# Set Date dynamically in extjs with value from backend

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

Back End is Java. front end is Extjs js.

When I set date in Java script as set value (new Date ), current date comes up in UI. when I set using back-end value date component is empty. Date comes up as string of numbers of length 13 in UI when  debug. Date. parse is not working. how do i set value in UI from back-end. date from back-end is Java util date.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the [dateFormat](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Date.html#cfg-dateFormat) using a [date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Date.html) model field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13 digit string of numbers you are talking about is [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) including milliseconds. You can convert the unix timestamp to whichever format you want at the frontend in ExtJS using [format](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-format) method of [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Date.html) package.

```
let unix_time = 1527496785000;
let formatted_time = Ext.Date.format(new Date(unix_time), "Y-m-d H:i:s");
console.log(formatted_time)  //2018-05-28 14:09:45
```

Comment: i converted the data from backend using new Date (value from backend). It solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: May i know how to do it other way round? i am passing date from ext js to Java and i am getting error that string cannot be converted to Date. But in js i have it as Date obj

Comment: Better to send the date as a 13 digit long string. you can convert a date object to a long using getTime() method of date object in javascript

Comment: in Java the property is of type Java.util. date. when 13 digit string is passed from Extjs to Java, i am getting error String cannot be converted to Date object. how can i make sure that Java. util. date object reaches controller instead of 13 digit String

Comment: As far as my understanding java.util.Date constructor receives a long data type. so try converting it to long and pass that to Date constructor...
String timestamp = 1527496785000;
Date date = Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp));